# C# Lambda Operator

Tags: c#, lambda

In C#, when writing lambda expressions, is there a single-character version of the => lambda operator?

I know that it isn't very hard to type =>, but still...

Comment: No, that is the syntax. What a bizarre question.

Comment: No, it's not like the Pascal assignment operator := that is an alias for a single character (left arrow) that doesn't exist in a regular character set any more. The `=>` operator is two characters.

Comment: Now that was funny. For my next question, How can I make regex less verbose. :)

Answer (score 7):

No.  The two characters (`=>`) are required.  This is the way the language was written and designed.

Just be thankful - it's far shorter than the older `delegate { ... }`  syntax in most cases.